# Multiple choice from database without <select>

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to make a form with Symfony to be able to select multiple choice by checking checkboxes without having a **<select>** dropdown alone in my form.

Theses choice come from a table in my database, each row must be a choice possibility in my form.

For example table **T_Choices** :

| ID | Choices |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Choice_1 |
| 2 | Choice_2 |

I'm able to create the form with many checkbox as there are rows.

But how can i submit this "dynamic" form and get thoses data in one "array" in my controller to have for example `$form["choices"]->getData()[0]` or 1 or 2 etc.

Thank you for your help. And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: A select without a <select> can you give an example of code of what you've been trying to help to understand. Also have you read https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html
If that did'nt solve your issue, please edit your question and provide code details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving those checkboxes the same value for the name-attribute and adding square brackets at the ending `[]`.
You probably need:

```
<input id="1" name="choices[]" type="checkbox" value="1"><label for="1">Choice_1</label>
<input id="2" name="choices[]" type="checkbox" value="2"><label for="2">Choice_2</label>
```